# Laravel Eloquent - Find Items where Column A is a substring of Column B

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get results where one column is a substring of a second clolumn.

Example:

```
ID | Hostname         | Domain
-----------------------------------------
1  |  abc.x.acme.com  |  acme.com  
2  |  xx.corp2.com    |  acme.com 
3  |  int.corp.com    |  corp.com
```

So the results here should be ID 1 and 3 as Domain is a substring of the hostname.

Thanks!

Comment: is your database mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$result = yourEntity::whereRaw("Hostname LIKE CONCAT('%', Domain,'%')")
              ->get();
```